# Formatting factors as dates turns all dates into N/A

Tags: r, csv

I've imported a CSV into R with two columns: Date and No. of links discovered, the aim is to create a line graph showing the number of links built to a website. My CSV looks like this:

```
       Date| No.of.Links.Found|
1| ï»¿2011-09-12|                 2|
2|    2011-10-03|                 1|
3|    2011-10-10|                 1|
4|    2011-10-12|                 2|
5|    2011-10-14|                 2|
6|    2011-10-15|                 3|
```

(Not sure what those strange characters are, but they also appear in R.)

However on importing the CSV, the date column is formatted as a factor. When I try

```
Links_Over_Time$Date<-as.Date(Links_Over_Time$Date,format = "%y/%m/%d")
```

All date values are replaced with 'N/A'.

```
Date No.of.Links.Found
1 <NA>                 2
2 <NA>                 1
3 <NA>                 1
4 <NA>                 2
5 <NA>                 2
6 <NA>                 3
```

I've also tried:

```
Links_Over_Time$Date<-as.POSIXct(as.character(Links_Over_Time$Date), format = "%y/%m/%d")
```

and same thing happens. I also tried

```
library(lubridate)
Links_Over_Time$Date<-ymd(Links_Over_Time$Date)
```

but I get "All formats failed to parse. No formats found." warning message.

This CSV is an export from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Your date format looks like `%Y-%m-%d`

Comment: `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`

Comment: While converting, some program might have added `ï»¿` to the beginning of the file. You can remove those manually in the source file just before you import it into R.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. @akrun I tried changing the date to the format you suggested but the same issue kept happening.

Comment: @jwells I added that in to my import argument but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I opened the file in Excel and those characters weren't there. Also excel reads these as dates

Comment: it still imports that variable as a factor?

Comment: if it imports that as character it should work. use `as.Posixct` and you're set

Comment: It formats it as character strings.
I'm wondering if those strange characters are messing things up at all?

Comment: Heh, Excel. Try Notepad++ (assuming you have a .csv or some other text file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu should use "-" instead of slash ("/"):

```
options(stringsAsFactors=F)

Links_Over_Time$Date<-as.Date(Links_Over_Time$Date,format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

I have imported your data into my r console and tried the above command, I got correct result apart from first record, so I remove garbage from data using below command from first row:
Use `Encoding(df$column_name)` and set it to "UTF-8" as below.Here column_name is the column which has issue of garbage data.

```
library(stringr)
Encoding(df$bcol) <- "UTF-8"
df$bcol1 <- str_replace(df$bcol,"(.*)(?=\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{1,2})","")
df$dt <- as.Date(df$bcol1,format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

Below is the Output(I have named the columns as acol,bcol and ccol for simplicity), **dt is the final column where your cleaned up data for date is residing:**

```
> df$dt <- as.Date(df$bcol1,format="%Y-%m-%d")
> df
  acol                  bcol ccol         dt
1 1  <U+0095><c8><c0>2011-09-12 2 2011-09-12
2 2                  2011-10-03 1 2011-10-03
3 3                  2011-10-10 1 2011-10-10
4 4                  2011-10-12 2 2011-10-12
5 5                  2011-10-14 2 2011-10-14
6 6                  2011-10-15 3 2011-10-15
    bcol1
1 2011-09-12
2 2011-10-03
3 2011-10-10
4 2011-10-12
5 2011-10-14
6 2011-10-15
```

> 

Comment: Thanks this did the trick! I think those strange characters were confusing things.

Answer (score 0):

```
Links_Over_Time <- read.csv('filepath/filename', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Sorry didn't mean link... that comment was added automatically. You should add an explanation to your answer though to help describe why that line of code helps answer the asker's question